# Gradle not processing annotation processor first

Tags: android, gradle, build, annotation-processing

I'm having a problem with a Gradle build. In my project I'm using an annotation processor made by myself. This processor generates some source files on the last round of processing. In the generated files there's one class in particular (Revolver) that is referenced by the code of the project. The problem is that Gradle seems to start the annotation processor and the compilation at the same time. This gives an error since the generated classes are not ready and thus not found.

In order to verify this, I've added some debug logging.

```
Note: Starting Revolver Injector generation
Note: Starting Revolver Component Provider generation
Note: Starting Revolver Injector generation
Note: Starting Revolver Component Provider generation
E:\workspace\Android Studio\fix-in-produzione\branches\videocurriculum-client-android\app\src\main\java\co\aurasphere\videocurriculum\view\activity\NetworkBaseActivity.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
import co.aurasphere.revolver.Revolver;
                         ^
 symbol:   class Revolver
 location: package co.aurasphere.revolver
Note: Starting Revolver Injector generation
warning: File for type 'co.aurasphere.revolver.Revolver' created in the last round will not be subject to annotation processing.
Note: Starting Revolver Component Provider generation
warning: File for type 'co.aurasphere.revolver.RevolverComponentProvider' created in the last round will not be subject to annotation processing.
1 error
2 warnings
```

As you can see, after the error, there are more outputs from the annotation processor (marked with "Note:").

This works flawlessly with Maven and used to work with Gradle 1.5. Now I'm using Gradle 2.14.

Can anyone explain to me if something had changed and/or how can I solve this problem?

These are my gradle files:

**main.gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
       jcenter()
       mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.1'

       // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
       // in the individual module build.gradle files

   }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
   }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**app.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"
    dataBinding{
        enabled true
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "co.aurasphere.videocurriculum"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
        incremental false
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
}

preBuild.dependsOn clean

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    // Revolver
    compile 'co.aurasphere.revolver:revolver:0.0.1'
    annotationProcessor 'co.aurasphere.revolver:revolver-compiler:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

    // Butterknife dependencies
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.0.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.0.1'

    // Retrofit
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:logging-interceptor:2.7.5'

    // Otto
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.8'

    // Support libraries
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.0.0'

}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you generate classes after the last round? Have you considered doing so during initial rounds instead?

Comment: @user1643723 I tried it but since I'm working on the same files, I get a FilerException: Attempt to recreate a file. So, I'm writing only once, in the last round.

Comment: I am not sure if this still works, but the official documentation mentions keeping the open file around and appending the "tail" during the last round. May be worth trying (if only to look how different compiler versions fail horrendously). Is locating the `Revolver` via reflection an option?

Comment: I know this is a pretty old question, but I can safely say that the order is not an issue here. Annotation Processing happens during compilation, it is a feature of the java compiler. The process works essentially like this: Reading and analyzing Source Files -> Annotation Processing -> Compilation of source code. So if the generated class would have been successfully generated it would be found by the time compilation starts. The issue must be something completely different. However without seeing the source code its not possible to say what specifically the problem might be.

Comment: @XaverKapeller this question is still open and I haven't found a solution yet. After days of debugging I came to that conclusion as well. The odd thing is that Android Studio can resolve the sources so it may be something with the apt plugin not able to put the classes on the right folder? I don't really know, I have very few knowledge of Gradle but I'm still not giving up!

Comment: Any hope? Problem Solved ? @Aurasphere

Comment: Still no solution to this... But I haven't tested it with the latest version of Gradle and Android Studio yet

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: Unluckily, no :(

Comment: Nope, I just abandoned the project